# Deploy .asmx (not WCF) web service on windows 7

Tags: web-services, windows-7, asmx

I need to deploy an old style .asmx asp.net web service (not WCF) on a windows 7 machine for test reasons. However it seems that just deploying it on a virtual directory or new web site on IIS won't cut like it used to back in xp.

What should I do? I need to test the service locally prior to deploying it, and so far it's giving me a hard time.

Any help will be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: What errors are you receiving? You should be able to configure the VirtualDirectory and ApplicationPool and let it rip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deploying to a Virtual Directory should work just like it did in XP...with one minor change.

The default behavior in IIS7 is to use 'Integrated' Managed Pipeline Mode for your Application Pools. More than likely, you just need to change that to 'Classic' Managed Pipeline Mode (or switch your Web Service over to use the built-in 'Classic ASP.NET' App Pool).